# Veeam Zip fails with different error messages

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, veeam

I'm having issues with Veeam Zip 6.5.  I'm trying to backup to a NAS that I have done successfully at 3 other locations but for some reason this one location is throwing errors.  It fails on "Processing (Computer Name)".  I've tried backing up using an mapped drive and directly to the nfs shares from the NAS with no success. Has anyone else resolved this issue?

Thanks
msindle

Comment: Here is some more information, 11/12/2012 4:40:17 PM :: SetVmChangeTracking failed, vmRef '16', changeTrackingEnabled 'True'
Failed to execute SOAP command "CReconfigVmOperation". Details: "<RestrictedVersionFault xmlns="urn:vim25" xsi:type="RestrictedVersion" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></RestrictedVersionFault>"
fault.RestrictedVersion.summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this issue is associated with the free version of ESXi. The free version does not have the proper features enabled for VeeamZip to work.